# How to send data from a form data to a database using ReactJS , Node.js and MySQL queries?

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs

I currently have my database set up with tables and it is correctly connected to the node server. The problem is that when it executes it stores the values as null or undefined which makes me feel like that I am not correctly sending the data from  the form.

Below is my Reactjs component file which contains a form and handle functions

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class RegisterComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      username: '',
      email:'',
      password:'',


      };
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();


    const data = { username:this.state.username, email:this.state.email , password:this.state.password }

    fetch('/api/createAccount', { method: 'POST', 

    body: JSON.stringify(data), // data can be `string` or {object}!

    headers:{ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } })

    .then(res => res.json())

    .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))

    .then(response => console.log('Success:', response));
   }



  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label htmlFor="username">Enter username</label>
        <input id="username" name="username" type="text" />

        <label htmlFor="email">Enter your email</label>
        <input id="email" name="email" type="email" />

        <label htmlFor="password">Enter a password</label>
        <input id="password" name="password" type="text" />

        <button>Send data!</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default RegisterComponent;
```

Below is the api request script

```
app.post('/api/createAccount', function(req, res) {
    const username = req.body.username;
    const password = req.body.password;
    const email = req.body.email;



  con.query(`INSERT INTO usertest2 SET username = ? , email = ? , password = ? `, [username , email, password] ,  function(err, result) {

  console.log(username);
  if (err) throw err;
      res.send(' successfully');

    });


  });
```

Comment: Is your app using `bodyParser()`? What gets printed when you `console.log(req.body.username)`?

Comment: yes it is @KevinHernandez when i tried that command you requested it prints undefined

Comment: app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

Comment: Add `app.use(bodyParser.json())` and get rid of `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have a function changing your state values. Make something like:

```
handleChange = (e) => {
  this.setState({
    [e.target.name]: e.target.value
  })
}
```

Then add those to the `onChange` for all of your inputs:

```
<input id="password" name="password" type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

Comment: sorry im new to react and node. but do i repeat this handleChange() for each input so like for the username , password, email. Or can I put is all underneath by repeating this.state

Comment: You would add `onChange={this.handleChange}` to each `<input>` element

Comment: ah ok , I shall try this now